# Avoid edge intersection in graphviz

Tags: graphviz

Suppose we have the following simple graph:

```
digraph Test {

    Start[shape = doublecircle];
    Foo[shape = square];
    Bar[shape = diamond];
    Baz[shape = square];
    Xyz[shape = square];

    Start -> Foo;
    Foo:s -> Bar:n;
    Bar:w -> Baz:n;
    Bar:e -> Xyz:n;
    Baz:s -> Foo:n;

}
```

Which is rendered as follows:

[image: Rendered graph]

Is there a way to tell graphviz to draw edge `Baz -> Foo` without intersections with `Foo -> Bar` nor `Bar -> Baz`?

Answer (score 6):

when it comes to graphviz layout, the best you can do is trying as much as possible to not interfere :)

taking out compass_pt from your file:

```
digraph Test {

    Start[shape = doublecircle];
    Foo[shape = square];
    Bar[shape = diamond];
    Baz[shape = square];
    Xyz[shape = square];

    Start -> Foo;
    Foo -> Bar;
    Bar -> Baz;
    Bar -> Xyz;
    Baz -> Foo;

}
```

and you get:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Adding an invisible node should do the trick:

[image]

```
digraph Test {

    Start[shape = doublecircle];
    Foo[shape = square];
    Bar[shape = diamond];
    Baz[shape = square];
    Xyz[shape = square];

    // "invisible" node to connect baz to foo
    BazToFoo [shape=none, label="", height=0, width=0]

    Start -> Foo;
    Foo:s -> Bar:n;
    Bar:w -> Baz:n;
    Bar:e -> Xyz:n;
    Baz:s -> BazToFoo [dir=none] // remove the arrowhead
    BazToFoo -> Foo:n;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

While I agree with [Guy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20458103/63733) to keep it simple, here's an alternative approach with some changes to eliminate the edge crossings.

```
digraph Test {
    Start[shape = doublecircle, group=a];
    Foo[shape = square, group=a];
    Bar[shape = diamond, group=a];
    Xyz[shape = square];
    Baz[shape = square];

    Start -> Foo;
    Foo:s -> Bar:n;
    Bar:e -> Baz:n;
    Bar:w -> Xyz:n;
    Baz:s -> Foo:n[constraint=false];
}
```

[image: modified graphviz graph with no edge crossings]

I found that graphviz's layout doesn't easily route edges back up along the outer left side of a graph. Probably the way the layout algorithm works, allowing the graph to expand to the right and bottom only.

That's why I switched the positions of the bottom nodes, having the node with the returning edge at the right side.